# How to handle general exceptions in PL/SQL

Tags: oracle, plsql

I looked at Google and here but couldn't find an answer for this.

I don't want to treat all exceptions in Oracle.

What I want is just get the return code of the last statement and check if it is 0 (zero). If it is, the command was executed ok. If not, there was some error and then I want the procedure to exit and raise a message saying only that there was an error and the command that caused that error.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Check value of `SQLCODE`. It is either 0 or the error code.

Comment: I used it like this: 
"DELETE FROM HS_CONTA_HERARCHY_LR;
  EXCEPTION WHEN OTHER THEN ecode := SQLCODE; emesg := SQLERRM; dbms_output.put_line(TO_CHAR(ecode) || '-' || emesg); goto END_PROC;"

Comment: Not sure if it is right... from what I read when I use "WHEN OTHER" it means "WHATEVER ELSE THAN 0". Is that right?

Comment: Yes, you are right, `WHEN OTHERS` means that exception is raised no matter what error it is.

Comment: Other thing is that should I put this EXCEPTION block within BEGIN/END ? When I compiled the procedure SQL Developer reised me this error msg: "Error(13,3): PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "EXCEPTION" when expecting one of the following:     ( begin case declare end exit for goto if loop mod null    pragma raise return select update when while with    <an identifier> <a double-quoted delimited-identifier>    <a bind variable> << continue close current delete fetch lock    insert open rollback savepoint set sql execute commit forall    merge pipe purge "

Answer (score 2):

If I'm interpreting your question correctly, it sounds like you want to ignore all exceptions and manually check the SQLCODE after every statement. If my understanding is correct, I'm afraid there's not really a way to do that in PL/SQL. When errors occur the system WILL raise an exception - there's no way around it. What you CAN do is to record a description of where the program is in its execution and print that from a generic exception handler, similar to the following:

```
PROCEDURE SOME_PROCEDURE IS
  strCheckpoint  VARCHAR2(2000);
  rowSome_table  SOME_TABLE%ROWTYPE;
BEGIN
  strCheckpoint := 'SELECT FROM SOME_TABLE';
  SELECT *
    INTO rowSome_table 
    FROM SOME_TABLE
    WHERE SOME_COLUMN = 42;

  strCheckpoint := 'UPDATE SOME_OTHER_TABLE';
  UPDATE SOME_OTHER_TABLE
    SET A_COLUMN = rowSome_table.A_COLUMN
    WHERE KEY_COLUMN = rowSome_table.KEY_COLUMN;
EXCEPTION
  WHEN OTHERS THEN
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Something happened at checkpoint ''' ||
                         strCheckpoint ||
                         ''' SQLCODE=' || SQLCODE ||
                         ' SQLERRM=' || SQLERRM);
    RETURN;
END;  -- SOME_PROCEDURE
```

Share and enjoy.

Comment: Seems to be exactly what you put here. I don't need to handle an exception, but the Procedure must stop if anything out of the normal flow happens. In this case, using OTHERS, I think Oracle will know that something happened and then it can stop. What I used was a GOTO statement in the exception block that goes to a NULL at the last line of the procedure.

Comment: -1 Why do you have `RETURN;` there? It does exactly nothing. It's very poor practice to swallow all exceptions and do nothing with them except put something to DBMS_OUTPUT which will probably never be read by anyone.

Comment: Also, you've added an additional END in there without a corresponding BEGIN.

Comment: @JeffreyKemp - corrected the extra END. OP indicated a desire to manually check the SQLCODE after every procedure call. While I don't agree with doing this, the above is an example of a way in PL/SQL to allow this - thus, the RETURN statement in the exception handler is there to indicate that the procedure is being intentionally exited rather than propagating the exception upwards. Share and enjoy.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure I got your problem right but does this look like you need ?

```
SQL> create function get_number return number
  2  is
  3  begin
  4   return 1;
  5  end;
  6  /


SQL> begin
  2   if get_number != 0 then
  3  raise_application_error(-20000,'Error raised !');
  4  end if;
  5  end;
  6  /
begin
*
Error in line 1:
ORA-20000: Error raised ! 
ORA-06512: на  line 3
```

or

```
SQL> declare
  2   user_def_exc exception;
  3  begin
  4   if get_number!=0 then
  5     raise user_def_exc;
  6   end if;
  7  exception
  8   when user_def_exc then
  9     dbms_output.put_line('We ave got a problem');
 10  end;
 11  /
We ave got a problem
```

Comment: That is it, but in a Procedure. I am abou to do it like this:

 "DELETE FROM HS_CONTA_HERARCHY_LR; EXCEPTION WHEN OTHER THEN ecode := SQLCODE; emesg := SQLERRM; dbms_output.put_line(TO_CHAR(ecode) || '-' || emesg); goto END_PROC;"

Comment: OK, I would recommend to use raise_application_error function instead of dbms_output. DBMS_OUTPUT package works just in PL/SQL together with SQL*Plus and if you want to get the error message from Java/C++/C# application it's worth to use customize exception throw.

Comment: Actually this will be called only by SQL*Plus.

Comment: I would recommend not to use `when others` unless your client do not want to see ORA errors, Oracle itself throws exception with suitable error message.

Comment: @Lucas Rezende, if you want to percept just specific case you may use user-defined exception (I added it to my example). As San said above when others then is not the best way to handle exceptions as it swallows all ones.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following in SQLPLus:

```
SQL>whenever sqlerror exit 1
```

This will terminate the execution of your script upon an error with exit value 1